# why html tag can be styled and seen?

Tags: html, css

I was playing around with css and discovered problems in browsers like ie7 with margins, I ended up styling the html tag in the css for things to look good. How is it that the html tag can be styled when the body tag is supposed to be the start of the visible portion of a html document?

Comment: you can style any tag in your html document...even your custom tags, how they behave etc, kinda `display: block;` to render it as a block level or anything else..

Comment: What makes you believe that "the body tag is supposed to be the start of the visible portion of a html document"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, in terms of CSS, the [viewport](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#viewport) is the canvas where all the contents of a page are drawn, followed by [`html`, the root of an HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.3), followed by [`body`, the document body](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5). The `body` element may be the start of an HTML document where visible content may be placed, but it's not the root of the view canvas, at least as far as CSS is concerned.

And for that matter, even `head` and its contents may be styled, not just `html`, `body` and the contents of `body`. In fact, browsers that implement CSS actually have to apply `display: none` to the `head` element in their user agent stylesheets in order to hide it.